# check imap mail with heroku app

Tags: javascript, php, heroku

I get this error when I trying to cal this code on heroku.

Whats the solution within the heroku?

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap-baxxxxxxta.net:143}", "*@baxxxx.pw", "0xxxx3");

echo "<h1>Posta kutuları</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap-bxxxxxxxxxxet:143}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "İşlem başarısız oldu<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}


Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in /app/imaptest.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the IMAP extension for PHP is installed.

Heroku supports built-in PHP extensions, they can be enabled by adding them as a requirement in your composer file. To enable IMAP, add the requirement to your project's `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "vendor/project",
  "require": {
    "ext-imap": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: yes how can I make sure within in heroku do you know how can I install on heroku

Comment: The following built-in extensions have been built “shared” and can be enabled through composer.json (internal identifier names given in parentheses):

Comment: as heroku stated like that but how can I add on

Comment: Add `"ext-imap": "*"` to the requirements in your composer.json.

Comment: i have no composer.json in directory I followed normal build

Comment: In that case, add it to your projects root folder. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation for more information.

Comment: ERROR: Your 'composer.json' lists dependencies inside 'require',
remote:        but no 'composer.lock' was found. Please run 'composer update' t
remote:        re-generate 'composer.lock' if necessary, and commit it into you
remote:        repository. For more information, please refer to the docs at
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation
remote: 
remote:  !     Push

Comment: As it states, add the composer.json locally, run `composer update` and commit/push the changes.